# AttributeError: module 'transformers.modeling_bert' has no attribute 'gelu'

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

from cdqa.utils.filters import filter_paragraphs
from cdqa.utils.download import download_model, download_bnpp_data
from cdqa.pipeline.cdqa_sklearn import QAPipeline

# Download data and models
download_bnpp_data(dir='./data/bnpp_newsroom_v1.1/')
download_model(model='bert-squad_1.1', dir='./models')

# Loading data and filtering / preprocessing the documents
df = pd.read_csv('data/bnpp_newsroom_v1.1/bnpp_newsroom-v1.1.csv', converters={'paragraphs': literal_eval})
df = filter_paragraphs(df)

# Loading QAPipeline with CPU version of BERT Reader pretrained on SQuAD 1.1
cdqa_pipeline = QAPipeline(reader='C:/models/bert_qa.joblib')

# Fitting the retriever to the list of documents in the dataframe
cdqa_pipeline.fit_retriever(X=df)
```

I was trying to load model but the  cdqa_pipeline = QAPipeline(reader='C:/models/bert_qa.joblib') line throws an error saying AttributeError: module 'transformers.modeling_bert' has no attribute 'gelu'

I was using transformers version 3.5

Comment: Please try to upgrade to a more recent version. They have fixed a bunch of bugs.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, could you please share it? I have exactly that same problem.

Answer (score 0):

from transformers.activations import gelu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using a different version. Issue was I had a requirement for this version so I changed other parts of my program too.